# MKOverlay jumps when changing alpha of MKMapView in an animation

Tags: ios, jquery-animate, mkmapview, alpha, mkoverlay

I add multiple MKCircle's and one MKPolyline to an MKMapView. In an animationWithDuration I change the alpha of my instance of MKMapView from 1 to 0. The MKMapView disapears as expected, but at the start of the animation the MKOverlays (MKCircle's and MKPolyline) are jumping a few pixels.

```
        self.routeView.alpha = 0;        
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
            self.routeView.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {    
        }];
```

I added an example video showing the problem. In this video you see the change of alpha from 1 to 0 in 2 seconds en after the animation finished you see animating it back to 1 in 2 seconds. At the beginning of the first animation and at the end of the second you see a little jump.
[example video](http://we.tl/UlVj8sC9c8)

In the simulator you can't reproduce this problem, because the overlays disappear immediately. You should run it on a device instead.

Does anyone know what causes this problem and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your animation block to the older syntax. For my case, the block style was not working, but the old style did. This fixed my animation of the alpha.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

self.routeView.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```